# How to compile Razor views at runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET 5 MVC compiles Razor views at build time into assambly.

Some views can modifified by users after application is published.

How to include views in source code form (as cshtml files so that they can modified and compiled at runtime after modification ?

**Update**

Runtime compilation is enabled in Starup.cs.

Views directory does not appear in published output.

How to add Views as cshtml files so that they are compiled automatically at runtime.

Should Views directory created manually and cshtml files copied into it ? How to use those views in runtime by file name ?

How to update cshtml file in runtime and force application to use updated version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a bit more specific with your question.

cshtml Views by default CAN be modified at runtime and do not need to be compiled for the changes to take effect,

But your question asks if they can be "compiled" at "runtime". Runtime happens after compilation, so you cannot compile at runtime.

I think the answer you're looking for is that cshtml files do not need to be compiled again if changed at runtime

Comment: I want to update some cshtml file in runtime and force application to use updated version. I updated question and provided more information.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Enable Razor runtime compilation" while creating the project:

[image]

And here is the .csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Runtime compilaton in release mode is enabled and CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory is set to false. Views directory does not appear in publish output.  Should it created manually and changeable views copied into it ? How to use those views in controllers by file name ? I updated question